# In python pandas, how can I convert this formatted date string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I have tried several ways of using `to_datetime`, but so far I can only get it to return the dtype as "object"

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['28Dec2013 19:23:15']),dayfirst=True)
```

The return from this command is:

```
0    28Dec2013 19:23:15
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a `format` parameter to the [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['28Dec2013 19:23:15']),format="%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S",dayfirst=True)
>>> df
0   2013-12-28 19:23:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to convert existing columns in a dataframe here the solution using a helper function `conv` and the `apply` method.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def conv(x):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S')

series = pd.Series(['28Dec2013 19:23:15'])
converted = series.apply(conv)

0   2013-12-28 19:23:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score -1):

Pandas does not recognize that datetime format.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(Series(['28Dec2013 19:23:15']))
0    28Dec2013 19:23:15
dtype: object
>>> pd.to_datetime(Series(['28 Dec 2013 19:23:15']))
0   2013-12-28 19:23:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You will need to parse the strings you are feeding into the Series.  Regular expressions will likely be a good solution for this.