# How to convert a column of type integer to type datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a column (`"ADMIT_YEAR"`) of integers in a dataframe. A typical element in the column looks like: `200110`, where `2001` = year and `10` = month.  I need to convert this column to type datetime.

I succeeded in doing so using the clunky method below.  Could someone offer a more efficient way of writing this code?

```
Freshman['ADMIT_YEAR'] = Freshman['ADMIT_TERM'].astype(str).str.slice(0,4)
Freshman['ADMIT_MONTH'] = Freshman['ADMIT_TERM'].astype(str).str.slice(4,6)
Freshman['ADMIT_DATE_str'] = Freshman['ADMIT_YEAR']+'/'+Freshman['ADMIT_MONTH']
Freshman['ADMIT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(Freshman['ADMIT_DATE_str'], format="%Y/%m")
```

---

Note: I believe this question is not answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623156/how-to-convert-the-integer-date-format-into-yyyymmdd) since my dates are not integer days.

Comment: Related, but not exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31973895/189134

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just apply `pd.to_datetime` directly to (the string conversion of) the column, no need to use string slicing here:

```
Freshman['ADMIT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(Freshman['ADMIT_DATE'].astype(str), format='%Y%m')
```

There is no requirement for there to be a delimiter between the digits:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ADMIT_DATE': [200110, 201604]})
>>> df['ADMIT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADMIT_DATE'].astype(str), format='%Y%m')
>>> df
  ADMIT_DATE
0 2001-10-01
1 2016-04-01
>>> df.dtypes
ADMIT_DATE    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```